# Which operator is more powerful plus(+) or increment(++)

Tags: complexity-theory

```
s=0;
for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
{
s=s+1;
}
Modified:
s=0;
for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
{
s=s++;   //replace s=s+1
}
```

//    Does    it     reduce    the complexity? is ++ is less stronger or more //stronger than +.

Comment: What complexity and strength mean for you? Readability / performance...?

Answer (score 0):

Used in the way you present the question, there is no difference. In each case, you are simply incrementing a variable by 1. In fact, a decent optimizer is likely to generate exactly the binary code for these two pieces of code. However, if you want to increment by more than 1 (e.g., by 2, or by a variable amount), you will get better performance by directly doing s += 2 (or s += increment_amount) rather than by invoking s++ repeatedly to simulate a += increment.

In terms of big-O notation, as long as your increment amount is a constant, there is technically no difference in big-O complexity, although you will get a constant time speedup by using a "+=" over repeated "++" operations. If increment is not constant - i.e., if the increment amount is a function of the length of input - then the big-O complexity also changes.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of complexity, "s++" is the same as "s=s++" and therefore "s++" is the least complex. The purpose of "++" is to simplify the very common operation of incrementing a variable by one. Perhaps you were struggling with the question of the elegance of "++" and I hope this helps.